# Hide a div on click and show another until last

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a quiz layout that gets questions and answers from a database.

I currently have a next button to go through the questions , but **I would like to have it so that when an answer is selected , it goes to the next question**.

Each question/answer set has this div around it , with the id being the id of the question.

```
<div class="question container center" id="1" style="display: none;">
    <h1>Question</h1>
    Answer
    Answer
    Answer
    Answer
</div>
```

The answer buttons look like this :

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large blue-grey lighten-2 btn-width mcqtest">Answer</a>
```

The current Jquery im using is this :

```
$('#2, #3, #4, #5, #6, #7, #8, #9, #10, #11, #12, #13, #14, #15, #16, #17, #18, #19, #20, #21, #22, #23, #24, #25 ').hide();
$('#next').click(function(){
     //code
    var curr = $(".question:visible");
    var next = curr.next(".question");
    next.show();
    curr.hide();
    if (!next.next(".question").length) {
        $("button").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
         $("button").text("End of Test");
    }
});
```

Comment: Important thing, `id`s are not supposed to start with digits.

Comment: What is the element type of your Answer?

Comment: the answers are just styled a tags

Comment: Ok so you want to show the next question on click of the anchor tags right? Also the current ode which you have provided works fine too, right?

Comment: yes . The current jquery works because its a next button that its attached to.

Comment: This has nothing to do with php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `prop()` instead of `attr()` and I made some other changes.

```
$('.question').slice(1).hide();
$('#next, a.mcqtest').click(function(){
     //code
    var curr = $(".question:visible");
    var next = curr.next(".question");
    next.show();
    curr.hide();
    if (!next.next(".question").length) {
        $("button").prop('disabled', true);
        $("button").text("End of Test");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, change id's (#2, #3 etc) to a single class if possible. 
Next - extract your anonymous function from $('#next').click, then add click listener to every answer link so it would fire your "next question" function each time anyone selects answer.

For example (code without id's changed):

```
    function nextQuestion(){
    var curr = $(".question:visible");
    var next = curr.next(".question");
    next.show();
    curr.hide();
    if (!next.next(".question").length) {
        $("button").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
         $("button").text("End of Test");
    }
}

$('#2, #3, #4, #5, #6, #7, #8, #9, #10, #11, #12, #13, #14, #15, #16, #17, #18, #19, #20, #21, #22, #23, #24, #25 ').hide();
$('#next').click(nextQuestion);
$('a.mcqtest').click(nextQuestion);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this script and it must work as you requested.

```
$('a.mcqtest').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#next').trigger('click');
});
```